# How to handle bad Json response in C# using JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json

I am using a web service to get response and found the Json is not in the right format. Please see the below sample.

The Object structure is :

```
  public class Action
            {
                public string serialNumber { get; set; }
                public string method1 { get; set; }
                public string recipient1 { get; set; }
                public string notifyon1 { get; set; }
            }
```

We having a field "recipient1" which has value "1@test.com,2@test.com,3@test.com" then the api response the json as below.

Bad json response :

```
{"serialNumber": "2471", 
"method1": "email", 
"recipient1": "1@test.com", 
"2@test.com": "", 
"3@test.com": "", 
"notifyon1": "warning",
  "critical": ""}
```

Which is supposed to be :

```
{"serialNumber": "2471", 
"method1": "email", 
"recipient1": "1@test.com,2@test.com,3@test.com", 
"notifyon1": "warning,critical"}
```

First I was trying to using regex to convert these emails values to the right field. But then I found it is happened for all the value which include comma "," . Such as ”Notifyon1“ in the above sample.

Now I am thinking if there is any way I can do parse the json, when it find "2@test.com" then check the Object, if it is not a property then put it as a value into previous field "recipient1".

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work regardless of empty values in the properties.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

private Action HandleBadJson(string badJson)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(badJson);
    Action act = new Action();
    List<string> propertyNames = act.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
    string currentProperty = "";
    foreach (var keyValPair in dictionary)
    {
        if (propertyNames.Contains(keyValPair.Key))
        {
            currentProperty = keyValPair.Key;
            act.GetType().GetProperty(currentProperty).SetValue(act, keyValPair.Value);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            var currentValue = act.GetType().GetProperty(currentProperty).GetValue(act, null);
            string value = currentValue + "," + keyValPair.Key;
            value = value.Trim(',');
            act.GetType().GetProperty(currentProperty).SetValue(act, value);
        }
    }
    return act;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jhmt. Your function looks good. I'll test it. If there are empty values, any idea about it? Seems I can use the keyvalpair.key to compare with the object's properties then.

Comment: @AndyShao I've updated my code to handle the bad json if there are empty values.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you so much for help.